# Does increasing voltage or current increase intensity of em wave produced by antenna?

Tags: antenna

Will Increasing voltage or current affect frequency or wavelength of em wave?

Comment: I dislike questions with a dozen or less words in them. It usually means writing an encyclopedia in response. I think there is an inverse relationship between the number of words in a question and the number of words required to answer it. Must be a formula somewhere for that....

Comment: Voltage and current will affect the power, but not the frequency or wavelength (wavelength is directly related to frequency).

Comment: I've got the formula: \$N_{_\text{ANSWER}}=\frac{10^7}{N_{_\text{QUESTION}}}\$. Or thereabouts.

Comment: The answer to the _question_ is, "no".  And the answer to the _title_ is "yes".

Comment: Your question does not match the title.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, increasing the voltage or current feeding an antenna will increase the intensity of the em wave produced. NOTE: you do not have freedom to set both the voltage and the current. The antenna can only function when the ratio of voltage / current is at some constant value called the antenna impedance. The impedance may be a complex number.

The wavelength and frequency will not be affected by changing the voltage or current.